# Projection of Shapefiles for Spain (INE)

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, spain

I downloaded the official shapefiles for the municipalities of Spain from INE [here](http://www.ine.es/ss/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobheader=Unknown+format&blobheadername1=Content-Disposition&blobheadervalue1=attachment%3B+filename%3Dmapas_completo_municipal.rar&blobkey=urldata&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=508%2F229%2Fmapas_completo_municipal.rar&ssbinary=true).

It has a lot of shapefiles, but I found out that the right one for what I need is **esp_muni_0109.shp**.  I would like to convert these shapefiles to **WGS84** with **ogr2ogr**.  The problem is that these shapefiles have no .PRJ files, so I don't know from what projection system to convert them from.

Does anyone know the right projection system for these shapefiles and, if so, can anyone tell me what parameters to use with ogr2ogr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the right projection system is **ED50 / UTM zone 30N**.  Then, for the conversion, I created a .PRJ file with the information I found [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/23030/):

```
PROJCS["ED50 / UTM zone 30N",
    GEOGCS["ED50",
        DATUM["European_Datum_1950",
            SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388,297,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7022"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6230"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4230"]],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-3],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","23030"],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Finally, I used **ogr2ogr** with these parameters:

```
ogr2ogr destination.shp source.shp -t_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
```